# Way for wizard to cover level difference for Metamagic feats

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, wizard, metamagic

For Clerics there is Divine metamagic feat in Complete divine which let a cleric to exchgange daily turn attempts to pay metamagic feat level difference cost.

Such as, a cleric casts a Disintegrate spell (from destruction domain) and insead of casting it from 2 level higher slot, he gives up 2 turn atempts in exchange for metamagic level difference.

Is there a wizard equivalent of a such feat/ability that lets a wizard to exchange metamagic feat level difference with something else?

Comment: Are feats that simply lower that difference, without need to exchange anything, fine?

Comment: @Momonga-sama yeap, totally removing the level cost is preffered but it is ok for anything that will lower the cost too (:

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## The Divine Way

---

### Lose one spellcasting level and one more feat:

- Get one level of cleric in order to get access to a pool of turn attempts.
- Get any feat that lets you cast arcane spells as divine spells.
- Use the usual Divine Metamagic feat tree to apply metamagics to your divine wizard spells.

Southern Magic (Magic of Faerun) is a 3.0 feat and applies to a limited nuber of spells per day. It might be good for some metamagics that burn lots of turning attempts such as persist.

Alternative Source Spell (Dragon #325) is 3.5 and applies to any spell, but it slightly lowers the Caster Level for that spell.

---

### Lose one spellcasting level and be a divine wizard, sort of:

- Get one level of cleric in order to get access to a pool of turn attempts.
- Be an archivist, not a wizard. Get your wizardlike spells from the druid list, from the divine bard list, or from any domain list.
- Use the usual Divine Metamagic feat tree to apply metamagics to your archivist spells.

You will be surprised to see how many wizard spells can also be cast by some divine class. The archivist can learn them all. Also, archivists are close to wizards in flavor.

This, of course, only works if you're trying to metamagic some specific spells that are not in the cleric's list and that you can find in the other lists, and if you're not a wizard already.

If you are building a character at the high levels, consider taking a prestige class that gives you access to turning attempts, instead of the single cleric level.

---

## Going fully arcane

---

### Lose one spellcasting level and one feat (instead of Divine Metamagic):

- Aim for the Ultimate Magus PrC (Complete Mage).
- Fuel your metamagic with spontaneous spells from your other spellcasting class.

**If** you want to increase your wizard level as much as possible, you need to take the Practiced Spellcaster feat for your spontaneous casting class, in order to be able to progress wizard when the PrC offers you to go up one level in the lowest of your arcane classes.

---

### Probably not working for you:

- Metamagic Song (Races of Stone). Bardic music attempts are tied to bard levels, unlike turning attempts, and take too much away from Wizard.

Answer (score 4):

You are thinking of the *Divine Metamagic* feat. Note that the feat only applies to a single Metamagic feat chosen when taking it (say, *Heighten Spell* in your case). It is usually coupled with *Persist Spell* however, for cheese.

---

In the arcane tree, I do not know of any equivalent feat.

There are, however, two prestige classes that may be of interest:

- a *Spell Dancer 1* (D&D 3.0 *Magic of Faerûn*) may use her *Spelldance (Su)* ability to apply one or multiple metamagic feat by dancing for 1 full round for each level she raises the spell level before casting the spell; she has to succeed on a *Perform* check.
- an *Incantatrix 2* (D&D 3.5 *Player's Guide to Faerûn*) may use her *Cooperative Metamagic (Su)* to apply any one metamagic feat she knows to a spell being cast by another willing allied spellcaster; she has to succeed on a *Spellcraft* check. She agains further ways to apply metamagic or reduce the cost of metamagic as she progresses in level.

Answer (score 2):

### Feats

**Arcane thesis** (Player's Handbook II)

One chosen spell has decreased spell-slot cost for each metamagic applied.

> Choose one arcane spell that you can cast to be your thesis spell. [...] When you apply any metamagic feats other than Heighten Spell to that spell, the enhanced spell uses up a spell slot one level lower than normal.

**Easy metamagic** (Dragon Magazine #325)

Decreased spell-slot cost for one metamagic feat.

> Choose a metamagic feat you already have. When preparing or casting a spell modified by that feat, lower the spell-slot cost by one. You can never reduce the spell-slot cost below one level higher than the spell's actual level.

**Eldritch corruption** (Heroes of Horror)

Apply metamagic, damage allies' constitution score.

> You can enlarge, extend, heighten, or widen a spell, as though you had the appropriate metamagic feat, without increasing the spell level or, for spontaneous casters, casting time. You can apply any number of these metamagic effects to a spell in this way; if you choose heighten, then that spell's level is heightened by up to two levels. For each level of metamagic you apply, one of your allies takes 2 points of Constitution damage. In this case, "ally" is defi ned as someone who knowingly and willingly fi ghts alongside you against a common foe, or who otherwise considers you a trusted companion. You decide, when casting the spell, which ally takes the Constitution damage. You cannot select an ally immune to Constitution damage or an ally without a Constitution score. For purposes of this spell, you cannot designate a summoned or charmed being as your ally. You can use this feat three times per day.

**Forceful magic** (Dragon Magazine #308)

Once per day decrease metamagic spell-slot cost by 1.

**Metamagic School Focus** (Complete Mage)

3 times per day, decrease metamagic spell-slot cost by one for school of your specialisation or Spell Focus.

> Choose a school of magic for which you have the Spell Focus feat, or the school in which you have specialized. Three times per day, you can reduce by one level the cost of a metamagic feat applied to a spell of the chosen school. If you prepare spells, you can have only up to three such reduced cost spells prepared at any time.

**Metanode Spell** (Champions of Ruin)

Decrease metamagic spell-slot cost depending, by value depending on the layer and class of an earth metanode in which you stand.

> When casting a spell improved by a metamagic feat, you can deduct the class of the earth node layer in which you currently stand from the increased spell level. (The class of the layer does not equal the class of the node unless you are standing in the innermost portion of it.) For example, if you use Maximize Spell to augment the 3rd level spell fireball in the innermost (+1) layer of a Class 1 earth node, you cast the spell as if it were only two levels higher than normal, not three, because the earth node pays one spell level's worth of the metamagic cost. This feat is most useful to casters who do not prepare their spells (such as bards and sorcerers) and to wizards who rarely leave their earth nodes and can therefore prepare and cast their spells at the adjusted level.
> If you use this feat to reduce the cost of preparing a metamagic spell and then leave the earth node, the spell you prepared becomes unavailable until you return to an earth node layer of at least the same class as the one in which the spell was prepared

## Prestige classes

**Metaphysical Spell Shaper** (Book of Erotic Fantasy)

Get ability damage for applying metamagic feats and decrease metamagic's final spell-slot cost by 1.

> **Metamagic Manipulation (Su)**: At 1st level, a metaphysical spellshaper
> gains, the ability to cast metamagic spells spontaneously by taking
> ability damage instead of increasing the level of the spelL He chooses
> which of his ability scores to damage. All damage from a casting of a
> spell must go to the same ability.
>
> **Metamagic Mastery**: At 3rd level, the metaphysical spellshaper reduces
> the final spell-level slot required by metamagic feats by one (to a
> minimum of one).

**Halruan elder** (Shining South)

At 1st level and every 3 next levels decrease the spell-slot cost of chosen metamagic feat by one to a minimum of +1.

> Adroit Casting (Ex): The Halruaan elder has become so skilled at casting his spells with various metamagic feats that utilizing such feats has become easier for him. At 1st level, he picks a metamagic feat he knows. The cost in increased level of spell slots to use that metamagic feat is now permanently reduced by one level, to a minimum total modification of a spell's original level + 1. For example if a Halruaan elder with adroit casting 1 wishes to prepare an empowered magic missile, that spell takes up a slot only one level higher than its original level (instead of two). At 4th level, and every three levels thereafter, the Halruaan elder can choose another metamagic feat he knows. That feat gains the same benefit; spells altered by that feat take up a slot one level lower than normal (minimum of the spell's original level + 1). If the Halruaan elder doesn't have a metamagic feat to apply the ability to when he gains a level that grants adroit casting, or if he's has previously applied adroit casting to all of the viable metamagic feats he knows (any metamagic feats that require spells to occupt a slot two or more levels higher than normal), he gains no benefit from this ability until he aquires a new metamagic feat that adroit casting can affect. At that time, he can automatically designate that feat as altered by the unused application of adroit casting.

---

If you are interested in applying free metamagic to spells I'd recommend to read [this](http://brilliantgameologists.com/boards/index.php?topic=9876.0) article.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that the prestige class metaphysical spellshaper is from a third-party text.

Comment: @HeyICanChan simply adding source books would be enough?